# How to create multiple scheduled tasks with different fixed rates in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

I need to have two schedulers that each run at different fixed intervals. I also need the ability to stop and start the `quoteScheduler` based on whether or not the US stock market is open.

The `quoteScheduler` needs to run once per minute *if* the US stock market is open. But, I only need to check if the US stock market is open less frequently (say every 10 minutes). How can I set it up so that my `marketDataScheduler` runs every 10 minutes and can start and stop my `quoteScheduler` which will run every 1 minute only when the `marketDataScheduler` tells it to start.

Right now, the code below only follows the schedule configured by `MarketDataSchedulerConfiguration` and I am having trouble figuring out how to set up the two different schedules.

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class QuoteSchedulerConfiguration {

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
    public void scheduleByFixedRate() {
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class QuoteServiceScheduler {

    private final ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor;
    private final QuoteSchedulerConfiguration schedulerConfiguration;
    private final QuoteService quoteService;

    public QuoteServiceScheduler(QuoteService quoteService,
                                 ScheduledAnnotationBeanPostProcessor postProcessor,
                                 QuoteSchedulerConfiguration schedulerConfiguration) {
        this.postProcessor = postProcessor;
        this.schedulerConfiguration = schedulerConfiguration;
        this.quoteService = quoteService;
    }

    public void startSchedule() {
        postProcessor.postProcessAfterInitialization(schedulerConfiguration, "");
        quoteService.getLatestPrices();
    }

    public void stopSchedule() {
        postProcessor.postProcessBeforeDestruction(schedulerConfiguration, "");
    }
```

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
public class MarketDataSchedulerConfiguration {

    private final MarketDataScheduler marketDataScheduler;

    public MarketDataSchedulerConfiguration(MarketDataScheduler marketDataScheduler) {
        this.marketDataScheduler = marketDataScheduler;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedRate = 60 * 1000 * 10)
    public void scheduleByFixedRate() {
        marketDataScheduler.startSchedule();
    }
}
```

```
@Service
public class MarketDataScheduler {

    private final MarketDataServiceImpl marketDataServiceImpl;
    private final QuoteServiceScheduler quoteServiceScheduler;

    public MarketDataScheduler(MarketDataServiceImpl marketDataServiceImpl,
                               QuoteServiceScheduler quoteServiceScheduler) {
        this.marketDataServiceImpl = marketDataServiceImpl;
        this.quoteServiceScheduler = quoteServiceScheduler;
    }


    public void startSchedule() {
        if (isUSMarketOpen()) {
            quoteServiceScheduler.startSchedule();
        } else {
            quoteServiceScheduler.stopSchedule();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use the quartz scheduler.

Comment: Did you consider implementing this with a [trigger](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html#scheduling-trigger-interface) instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a simpler approach using `cron` to set the schedule instead of `fixedRate`. `cron` gives more precise control over when to run the job and can be set up to start the minute-by-minute update only when the US stock market is open. For example, below I am starting the job at 4:00 am eastern time to capture pre-market trading activity. Simply add this to a `MarketDataScheduler` and remove all the other classes that were attempting to simulate the precision provided by `cron`.

```
    @Scheduled(cron = "0 */1 4-16 * * MON-FRI", zone = "America/New_York")
    public void startSchedule() {

        boolean isMarketOpen = isUSMarketOpen();
        if (isMarketOpen) {
            quoteService.getLatestPrices();
        } else {
            LOGGER.info().log("US stock market is closed. Potential holiday - Closed during normal trading hours");
        }
    }
```